# Stochastic Ak model

Tags: macroeconomics

$$V^*(A_0,K_0)=max\sum\beta\sum P(A^t)\frac{c_t(A^t)^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}$$ st$$ k_{t+1}(A^t)+c_t(A^t)\leq Ak_t(A^{t+1})$$ $$A_t=1+u_t$$ $$u_t=\rho u_{t-1}+e_t$$ $$c_t(A^t),k_t{t+1}(A^t)\geq 0  \forall t$$

$e_t$ is an i.i.d. process with mean $0$ and $P(A_t)$ denotes the probability of a sequence $(A_0,A_1, ...,A_t)$

The associated Bellman, in this case, would be $$ V(k,A)=max \frac{c_t^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}+\beta E_t[V(k',A')|A]$$ st$$k'+c=Ak$$

Why it true that $E[V(k',A')|A)]=E[V(k',A')]$? Can we only justify it with the fact that we consider $\sigma\neq1$, it is i.i.d and that implies that the realization of $A'$ does not depend on A?

Suppose that the value function is: $V(k,A) = k^{1−σ}·V(1,A).$ Let us also define a function
$F(A)= V(1,A)$ so that $V(k,A) = k^{1−σ}· F(A).$ To solve for the value function, we will first verify that the guess is correct and then solve for F(A).

To prove it is right can we say that: $$E[V(k,A)|A]=E[k^{1-\sigma}V(1,A)|A]$$
$$=Ek^{1-\sigma}[V(1,A)|A]$$ $$=k^{1-\sigma}F(A)$$ which I guess $E[(.)|A]$ becomes $E[(.)]$ from the above mentioned.
$$V(k,A)=max[\frac{c^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}+\beta k^{1-\sigma}F(A])$$ st $$c+k'\leq Ak$$